# I am getting an error from MariaDb when trying to Add extra statement to working the query

Tags: php, mariadb, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I have a table with a lot of records. I need to check for duplicates.
I have the following query:

```
public function findduplicates(){
        $query =  $this->db->query(
            'SELECT book_id, auth_last , ebooks.ebook_title, storage_sys, ebook_path, AZ FROM ebooks
            INNER JOIN( SELECT ebook_title FROM ebooks  GROUP BY ebook_title HAVING COUNT(ebook_title) >1 ) temp ON ebooks.ebook_title = temp.ebook_title'
        );

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

The query produces the  following result in my view and this is what I am looking for:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [book_id] => 31
            [auth_last] => Aardenburg
            [ebook_title] => 06 Bas Banning en de Tour de France.epub
            [storage_sys] => 1
            [ebook_path] => Aardenburg, A van - 06 Bas Banning en de Tour de France.epub
            [AZ] => A
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [book_id] => 46
            [auth_last] => Van
            [ebook_title] => 06 Bas Banning en de Tour de France.epub
            [storage_sys] => 1
            [ebook_path] => Aardenburg A van - 06 Bas Banning en de Tour de France.epub
            [AZ] => B
        )

)
```

Because the table is very large I want to restrict my selection adding two parameter to my method:

```
public function findduplicates($sys_code,$folder_name){
        $query =  $this->db->query(
            'SELECT book_id, auth_last , ebooks.ebook_title, storage_sys, ebook_path, AZ FROM ebooks WHERE storage_sys = $sys_code AND AZ = $folder_name
            INNER JOIN( SELECT ebook_title FROM ebooks  GROUP BY ebook_title HAVING COUNT(ebook_title) >1 ) temp ON ebooks.ebook_title = temp.ebook_title'
        );
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

This gives me an error from MariaDb `near 'INNER JOIN...'`
I have tried with:

```
WHERE storage_sys = '.$sys_code.' AND AZ = '.$folder_name.'
```

with the same result and:

```
WHERE (storage_sys = `'.$sys_code.'` AND AZ = `'.$folder_name.'`
```

also with no luck.

Comment: `where` goes after `join`s. Also should parameterize query presuming those are values, not identifiers. If identifiers encapsulate in backticks (and check values or use whitelist). Returning `FALSE` is not useful. Use error reporting.

Comment: hoi @user3783243 thanks for your comment but I have tried that to with the same result I am doing something wrong for sure but I am not able to understand what that is. Really frustrating

Comment: Please update question to show update(s).

Comment: Is it CodeIgniter 3 or 4? You used the syntax from 3

Answer (score 1):

The `JOIN` goes before any `WHERE` clause. PHP variables should not be put directly in SQL, they need to be bound separately. Replace the variables with placeholders `?` and then bind them using `bind_param()`.

If you are using CodeIgniter then this is what is should look like:

```php
public function findduplicates():array {
    $sql = 'SELECT book_id, auth_last, ebooks.ebook_title, storage_sys, ebook_path, AZ 
        FROM ebooks 
        INNER JOIN( SELECT ebook_title FROM ebooks  GROUP BY ebook_title HAVING COUNT(ebook_title) >1 ) temp ON ebooks.ebook_title = temp.ebook_title
        WHERE storage_sys = ? AND AZ = ?';
    $db->query($sql, [$sys_code, $folder_name]);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` is part of `FROM` not of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT book_id, auth_last , ebooks.ebook_title, storage_sys, ebook_path, AZ FROM ebooks
INNER JOIN( SELECT ebook_title FROM ebooks  GROUP BY ebook_title HAVING COUNT(ebook_title) >1 ) temp ON ebooks.ebook_title = temp.ebook_title'
 WHERE storage_sys = '$sys_code' AND AZ ='$folder_name'
```

Also you miss single quotes around strings.

And you should learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: The single quotes should be replaced by placeholders and the values should be bound separately. Please do not encourage the wrong way

Comment: It'd be best if you showed how to do it. :)

Comment: @Dharman Thank for all of this but I was not concerning about security in this case because this app will run on a local host on my computer only. The suggested answer gives also an error telling me that 'A' (the value of $folder_name) in not a valid column. This error I have also had  before during my attempts

Comment: @Franco Do you have added the single quotes?

Comment: @Franco I wasn't talking about security in this context. If you don't do it as I said using prepared statements then your SQL will be broken.

Comment: @Jens yes I did and I had to add also the separation dots before and after the $vars to avoid an other upcoming error

Comment: @Darman, thanks for the advise. Many years ago I was using parameters binding already. The problem is that having used Codeigniter for the last 10 years I didn't had the needs to do that anymore. So having sad that in the case of this query I don't also know how to translated in code igniter queries so I am not able to make this query in the proper and secure way. A long time of programming is behind me and (I am 78 year od now) I have also to admit that my brain is to slow and to week. But this is and always will be my passion that's  why I ask once in a while for help.